# Exclude a datetime and the associated team sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I exclude in sql a datetime and the associated team: 
I´ve tried this here:

```
 IntervalDate not like ('2015-01-10 00:00:00' + 'Team C')
```

Comment: I think this needs a little more information, what does the table look like and the datatypes?

Comment: Are you storing timestamps in a character column...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have split the condition as :-

```
IntervalDate not like '2015-01-10 00:00:00'  and Team not like 'Team C')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per other comments.  I suspect that the "Team C" value resides in a separate column to `IntervalDate` and that `IntervalDate` is an SQL `datetime` (or similar) column.  If you can show us your table schema we can suggest what is correct, however it is going to be something like:

```
WHERE (IntervalDate NOT LIKE '2015-01-01' AND Team = 'Team C')
```

However, I am making assumptions because you've not shown us your table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use the LIKE statement unless really needed as your performance will be impacted.

Also, you probably don't want the full timestamp included with your date.  So, I would write something like:

```
$date = '2015-01-10';
$team - 'Team C';

$sql = "select * from TABLE 
    where date_format(IntervalDate, '%Y-%m-%d') <> $date 
    and team = $team";
```

But, without further DB schema information, it is hard to be more precise